# What is the Lubavitcher Rebbe's position on gentiles in the Land of Israel

Tags: gentiles, eretz-yisrael, chabad, chassidic-rebbe

The Rebbe, as is well known, held that it was assur to give away any parts of Eretz Yisrael. But I've never heard what his position on the gentiles living there was.  If Judea and Samaria were to be annexed would the Arabs be given citizenship or did he support their expulsion like Rabbi Kahane?

Comment: How do you know he addressed the issue?

Comment: You've presented a glaring [false dichotomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma).

Comment: I am assuming that since he opposed the giving away of the land then he would support its annexation into the State of Israel. I don't know if he addressed this issue.  That is why I asked.

Comment: @ShlomoKirschner giving away land is different than not taking it.  And is the West Bank included in the Lubavitcher Rebbe's particular borders of Eretz Israel?

Comment: Sorry I don't see how your comment is relevant.  Also I have not heard of anyone who says that the West Bank is not part of Eretz Yisrael.